# How to mark calendar days between two dates?

Tags: 7, datetime

I added two cck for start date and end date. I want to mark the dates on calendar.

If I select the start date and end date in single field by enabling requires `to date` option it works fine.

But I have a different date field for end date.How to do it?

Comment: Why not just removed the extra field and use the "to date" option instead?

Comment: I did the same now.

Comment: Is there any reason why you could not just use a single date field and use that option? You know there is that possibility, but you don't say why you don't use it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes.. because I the event have start date and end date. Between these days the time of event should be same. So that I keep different time field.

Comment: In that case, using a single date field should not be the solution, should it be?

Comment: Date field is single but time field is different.

Comment: In the question you say that you could use a single date field and select an option, which means you know that is a possibility, but you have two date fields. In the answer you say you used a single date field. In other words, you know that _option A_ is possible, but you ask the question; then you answer the question saying that you used _option A_. What is the purpose of the question? Why did you ask the question if you already know the answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did this with the same date field and enabled the to date option.